# Can't share audio in Messenger if the name has a space

Tags: java, android, share, facebook-messenger

I'm writing an Android voice recorder app.
I have a button where I click to share my audio file.
But... I can't share it in Messenger if the name has a space.
Gmail doesn't have any problem with that.

I use this code:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/mp3");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+o));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `o` (`files[pos].getPath()`) to `Uri.fromFile(files[pos])`.